# How can we configure different columns preferences for each repository and cabinet in Documentum webtop

Tags: documentum, webtop

Currently when I set columns in "tool->preference" the same columns starts to show for all the repository, even if the columns/attribute I chose in first repository does not exists in 2nd repository. Still it shows those attributes/columns in second repository.

Comment: the thing you talk about is modifying user preferences for displaying columns. The thing you would like to achieve can be done with programatically within WDK framework with which Webtop is built upon.

Comment: can you help me with the filenames and path I should be looking for?

Comment: No, last time I did some WDK development was back in 2012 :D Additionally, it's not the thing you can ask here on SO, sorry